# Trying to append music items to array but getting out of range error (Swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, apple-music, apple-musickit

I have an app that locally prints out all of a users songs in a list.

This is the array:

```
var mySongs: [MPMediaItem] = []
```

This is how the songs are fetched:

```
self.mySongs = MPMediaQuery.songs().items ?? []
```

I want to loop through the mySongs array and add specific songs from it into newArray

```
for songs in mySongs{
        if songs.title == "Actin Crazy"{
            newArray[counter] = songs
            counter+=1
        }
    }
```

But I am getting this error:
Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

How do I figure out how/where its going out of range in order to fix this?

Comment: What exactly is “the hump”? Are you aware that the `title` is an Optional? Do you know what an Optional is?

Comment: @matt The title is there just for the example condition where in this case I would move a song to the array if it had the name I was looking for.

The hump for me was a bunch of errors that were being thrown my way.  I'm trying the below right now though and not getting any problems, what are your thoughts?

for songs in mySongs{
            if songs.title == "Wonderland"{
                newArray[counter] = songs
                counter+=1
            }
        }

Comment: Put real code in your question, give real error messages, ask specifically about what troubles you.

Comment: @matt Post updated, please let me know if this is better and better equipped for Stackoverflow.

Comment: To add an item to the end of an array use `newArray.append(songs)` - You can't just refer to an index that doesn't exist,

Comment: Like @Paulw11 already said just try this instead of looping: `let mySongs = ["MPMediaItem]
var newSongs: [String] = []

if let match = mySongs.first(where: { $0.title == "a" }) {
    newSongs.append(match)
}
print(newSongs)`

Comment: @Paulw11 This worked perfectly, thank you so much for educating me.

Comment: @LoVo wow!  I had no idea I could do this instead of looping.  Thank you for the enlightenment this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot append to an array by saying

```
newArray[counter] = ...
```

To see why, suppose the array is empty. Then you would be saying

```
newArray[0] = ...
```

But the array is empty. There is no `newArray[0]`! Therefore you will crash when app runs — with an out of range error! It is illegal at any time to subscript an array by a nonexistent index.

Instead, use `newArray.append(...)`. That is why it exists.

However, your code has many other issues. In particular the `title` of an MPMediaItem is an Optional. You would need to unwrap it safely to use it.

Comment: Thank you deeply for your answer Matt, and also for your critique on my question which will help me become better at using this site!  My code is running perfectly.  I will also look into how I can go about unwrapping safely the optional so I can avoid any issues.